# swift avplayer controller get fullscreen button

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm pretty new in ios programming. Please, help me to find native solution to get the same button in avplayer controller as it is in safari:
[image]

How to enable this button in right bottom corner and assign my action to it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find, how to change AVPLayerController controls. But I made custom player with my control panels, using container view and embedding AVPlayerController. [image]